# Thymeleaf template and Spring Boot : Creating a radio input from Java enum

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums, radio-button, thymeleaf

I would like to populate a radio input control in a Thymeleaf automatically from a Java enum type called "source". I am using Spring Boot in the backend. 
My controller initialises a list of the enum values like this:

```
this.sourcesAsList = Arrays.asList(Source.values());
model.addAttribute("sources", sourcesAsList);
```

This works fine, at least as far as the List is concerned (as I can see in the log output).

The Thymeleaf template then tries to instantiate a radio control based on this attribute in the model, like so:

```
<div th:each="source : ${sources}">
  <input type="radio" th:field="*{source}"  th:value="${source.value}"/><label th:text="| ${source.value} |">Should not see this !</label>
</div>
```

However, when I try to load this page, I get the following error:

```
[Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/feedbackapp2.html]")] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'source' available as request attribute
```

The enum is pretty simple:

```
public enum Source {
    VALONE, VALTWO, VALTHREE, VALFOUR;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name();
    }
}
```

It's the first time I work with Thymeleaf, so I guess it is just a simple syntax problem somewhere, but even after googling I couldn't find a working example. Any ideas? Is it possible at all to do this with an enum? If not, what kind of datatype would be more appropriate?

Thanks a lot. 
Cheers,

Martin

Comment: The problem is the th:field="*{source}". Probably you do not have such an attribute. Could you please post the code of your html page (feedbackapp2.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I played around a bit more and got it working. The following HTML snippet displays the radio buttons correctly based the list of Enums and also is wired to the model correctly, in that I received the selected value in the controller's POST method:

```
<div th:each="source : ${sources}">
  <input name="source" type="radio" th:value="${source}"/><label for="source" th:text="| &nbsp; ${source} |">Something is wrong !</label>
</div>
```

There were two problems:

- it is not necessary to access the name() attribute of the enum (so,
  using ${source} instead of ${source.name} is fine)
- instead of th:field, use the namne attribute of the input control

Thanks a lot to Periklis for the comment.