# Spring: Map and pass value as object form to controller to view

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am new to spring and am trying to pass a string value via radio button in a form to a controller, then to a view. I can do it with no problem if the controller @RequestParam type is string. But what I want to do next is map the radio button attrib value to an object such as:

```
@Component
public class ChoiceBean {
    private String choice;

    public String getChoice() {
        return choice;
    }

    public void setChoice(String choice) {
        this.choice = choice;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ChoiceBean{" + "choice=" + choice + '}';
    }
}
```

...but it returns null in the view. What am I doing wrong?

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032063/spring-mvc-bind-request-attribute-to-controller-method-parameter) to update my controller methods getChoice() & processChoiceGet().

Here are my files:

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
            http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>flashcards-springboot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>flashcards-springboot</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

form in html

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form action="processChoice" method="post">
                <input type="radio" name="choicebean" value="1" checked=true>1<br>
                <input type="radio" name="choicebean" value="2">2<br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </form> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class FileUploadController {

    private static final Logger slf4jLogger
            = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileUploadController.class);

    // Holds keys, values in order
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    @Autowired
    private Utils utils;

    @Autowired
    ChoiceBean choiceBean;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() throws IOException {
        return "home";
    }

    // Called from home view
    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public String handleFileUpload(
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Model model) {
        // Clear map in case of new file upload
        map.clear();
        try {
            // Add map to model
            model.addAttribute("theMap",
                    utils.mapInputStringToMap(file.getBytes()));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            slf4jLogger.error(FileUploadController.class.getName(), ex.getCause());
        }
        return "choice-1";
    }

    // Map object to attribute
    @ModelAttribute("choice")
    public ChoiceBean getChoice(HttpServletRequest request) 
    {
        return (ChoiceBean) request.getAttribute("choicebean");
    }

    @PostMapping("/processChoice")
    public String processChoiceGet(
        @ModelAttribute("choice") ChoiceBean choice, Model model) {

        // Log
        slf4jLogger.info("result: " + choice.getChoice());
        model.addAttribute("choice",choice.getChoice());
        return "flash-card";  
}
```

Output view

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${choice} + '!'" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**:
I added an array of numbers to be used as radio button display in handleFileUpload() [<-this works]; also removed getString() from choice:

```
@Controller
public class FileUploadController {

    private static final Logger slf4jLogger
            = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileUploadController.class);

    // Holds keys, values in order
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    @Autowired
    private Utils utils;
    @Autowired
    ChoiceBean choiceBean;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() throws IOException {
        return "home";
    }

    // Called from home view
    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public String handleFileUpload(
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Model model) {
        // Clear map in case of new file upload
        map.clear();
        try {
            // Add map to model
            model.addAttribute("theMap",
                    utils.mapInputStringToMap(file.getBytes()));
            model.addAttribute("sources", new String[]{"1", "2"});

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            slf4jLogger.error(FileUploadController.class.getName(), ex.getCause());
        }
        return "choice-1";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("choice")
    public ChoiceBean getChoice(HttpServletRequest request) 
    {
        return (ChoiceBean) request.getAttribute("choicebean");
    }

    @PostMapping("/processChoice")
    public String processChoiceGet(
        @ModelAttribute("choice") ChoiceBean choice, Model model) {

        // Log
        slf4jLogger.info("result: " + choice);
        model.addAttribute("choice",choice);
        return "flash-card";
    }
}
```

...and edited the form to try to capture the command object as 'choice', but value is ***still*** null in the view. How can I get the chosen radio button value as a string to display in the view?

```
<form th:object="${choice}" th:action="@{/processChoice}" method="post">
    <div th:each="source : ${sources}">
        <input name="source" type="radio" th:value="${source}"/>
        <label th:for="source" th:text="${source}">my label</label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks José Bardales for the suggestion. I was able to use that to make the thymeleaf radio button display look correct, but I wasn't able to get the selected value in the view, so my I ended up using a plain html form.

Below is my solution. It works, but I feel like there is a better way in the controller to bind the radio button value to the choicebean object in Spring but not sure.

Bean...

```
@Component
public class ChoiceBean {
    private String choice;
    // Getter, setter
}
```

Form...

```
<form action="processChoice" method="get">
    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice1" value="1" checked=true>1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radiochoice1" value="2">2<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Controller...

```
public String processChoiceGet(@RequestParam String radiochoice1,
        ChoiceBean choice, Model model) {
    choice.setChoice(radiochoice1);
    model.addAttribute("choice",choice);
    return "flash-card";
```

View...

```
<body>
    <p th:text="'choice is ' + ${choice.choice} + '!'" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `th:each`

```
<input type="radio" th:each="me : ${choice}" th:value="${me.choice}">
```

Comment: So, this is in the form, right? What is 'me' here? And where do my values 1 and 2 go?

Comment: Hm, do I need to do something like this where in the controller I create a small array of two integers [1, 2], then add that to the model, then return the string name of the form html file?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53124981/thymeleaf-template-and-spring-boot-creating-a-radio-input-from-java-enum

Comment: where do you get the content in 'choice'? Database?

Comment: Originally that came from my form radio button selection

Comment: Using the below link, in the controller I created a small array of two integers [1, 2], then added that to the model, and the radio buttons appear but still working on submit portion.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53124981/thymeleaf-template-and-spring-boot-creating-a-radio-input-from-java-enum